# Web Service Basic Authorization with Axis 1.4 Java client

Tags: java, web-services, axis, soap-client, webservice-client

I want to create a Java client for a SOAP web service with Basic Authorization. I generate a client in the Eclipse Oxy (Web Service Client) with Apache Axis 1.4 runtime. Our cases use Basic Authorization with required username, password and domain (Figure 1: SOUP UI tool).

[image]

In SOAP UI the service return success status, while java code return status 401  Unauthorized.

The following code is used when making a call to service (I send null content, because I only want to get success answer from service just like in SOAP UI tool):

```
IntegrationService_AdEl service = locator.getBasicHttpBinding_IntegrationService_AdEl();
    ((Stub) service)._setProperty(Call.USERNAME_PROPERTY,"test");
    ((Stub) service)._setProperty(Call.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "123");
    ((Stub) service)._setProperty("DOMAIN", "dmn");
    IntegrationService_AdElPersonScreeningCreateResponse c = service.personScreeningCreate(null);
```

I am wondering how to make a successful call with the parameters for Basic Authorization.

Thanks for the help.